# The number of minimal components of a dynamical system via certain invariants of corresponding cross product $C^*$ algebra, some precise examples

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, discrete-dynamical-systems

Let  $X$ be  a  compact Hausdorff space and $\alpha$   be  a  homeomorphism of $X$.

So we  have a  natural  action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $C(X)$ which generates the  cross product  algebra $C^*(X,\alpha)$. [It is well known that this algebra is simple if  and only if the dynamical system $(X,\alpha)$ is  a  minimal dynamical system, see Corollary VIII.3.9 of page 229 of the book $C^*$ Algebras by examples by Kenneth R. Davidson, "https://books.google.com/books?id=0TXteNfrzvcC&lpg=PA223&vq=minimal%20dynamical%20system&pg=PA229&output=embed")

Is  there a  precise example of  a  dynamical system whose minimality is not easy to prove  but the  simplicity of corresponding algebra is accessible and easy to investigate?

Is there  an example of  a  dynamical  system with a  finite number of  minimal  components such that the number of minimal  components can be precisely observed in the corresponding cross product algebra?

Comment: Regarding the second question, when there are no periodic points, there is a one-to-one correspondence between ideals in the crossed product algebra and closed invariant subsets of $X$, so the number of mininal components is equal to the number of maximal ideals in the crossed product.